# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException on developing games in java

Tags: java

I'm trying make fonts for a game but whenever I load it I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at image.ImageFont.load(ImageFont.java:78)
at image.ImageFont.<init>(ImageFont.java:47)
at image.ImageFontTest.init(ImageFontTest.java:26)
at image.GameCore.run(GameCore.java:65)
at image.ImageFontTest.main(ImageFontTest.java:11)
```

I also have the files for it:

ImageFontTest

```
public class ImageFontTest extends GameCore {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ImageFontTest().run();
}

private static final long TOTAL_TIME = 6500;

private ImageFont bigFont;
private ImageFont medFont;
private long remainingTime;
private CharMovement[] charMovement;

public void init() {
    super.init();

    remainingTime = TOTAL_TIME;
    // load image fonts
    bigFont = new ImageFont("fonts/big");
    medFont = new ImageFont("fonts/medium");

    String message = "Good Times!";
    int stringWidth = medFont.stringWidth(message);
    charMovement = new CharMovement[message.length()];
    for (int i=0; i<message.length(); i++) {
        charMovement[i] = new CharMovement(message, i,
            (screen.getWidth() - stringWidth) / 2,
            screen.getHeight() / 2);
    }
}

public void update(long elapsedTime) {
    remainingTime -= elapsedTime;
    if (remainingTime <= 0) {
        stop();
    }
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
    // erase background
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0,0,screen.getWidth(), screen.getHeight());

    // draw some aligned text
    medFont.drawString(g, "Left", 0, 0,
        ImageFont.LEFT | ImageFont.TOP);
    medFont.drawString(g, "Center", screen.getWidth()/2, 0,
        ImageFont.HCENTER | ImageFont.TOP);
    medFont.drawString(g, "Right", screen.getWidth(), 0,
        ImageFont.RIGHT | ImageFont.TOP);

    // draw seconds remaining
    String timeLeft = "" + (remainingTime / 1000);
    bigFont.drawString(g, timeLeft, 0, screen.getHeight());

    // draw moving characters
    double p = (double)(TOTAL_TIME - remainingTime) / TOTAL_TIME;
    for (int i=0; i<charMovement.length; i++) {
        charMovement[i].draw(g, p);
    }
}

/**
    Simple animation class to animate a character along a
    path.
*/
public class CharMovement {
    char ch;
    Point[] path;

    public CharMovement(String s, int charIndex, int x, int y) {
        int stringWidth = medFont.stringWidth(s);
        for (int i=0; i<charIndex; i++) {
            x+=medFont.charWidth(s.charAt(i));
        }
        ch = s.charAt(charIndex);

        path = new Point[4];

        // start offscreen
        path[0] = new Point(x-2000, y);

        // move to the center of the screen and pause there
        path[1] = new Point(x, y);
        path[2] = path[1];

        // "explode" at a random angle far away
        double angle = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
        double distance = 1000 + 1000*Math.random();
        path[3] = new Point(
            (int)Math.round(x + Math.cos(angle) * distance),
            (int)Math.round(y + Math.sin(angle) * distance));
    }

    /**
        Draws this character in the path, where p is the
        location in the path from 0 to 1.
    */
    public void draw(Graphics g, double p) {
        int points = path.length - 1;
        int index = (int)(p*points);
        p = p * points - index;
        Point start = path[index % path.length];
        Point goal = path[(index + 1) % path.length];
        int x = (int)Math.round(goal.x * p + start.x * (1-p));
        int y = (int)Math.round(goal.y * p + start.y * (1-p));
        medFont.drawChar(g, ch, x, y);
    }
}
}
```

ImageFont

```
/**
The ImageFont class allows loading and drawing of text
using images for the characters.

Reads all the png images in a directory in the form
"charXX.png" where "XX" is a decimal unicode value.

Characters can have different widths and heights.
*/
 public class ImageFont {

public static final int HCENTER = 1;
public static final int VCENTER = 2;
public static final int LEFT = 4;
public static final int RIGHT = 8;
public static final int TOP = 16;
public static final int BOTTOM = 32;

private char firstChar;
private Image[] characters;
private Image invalidCharacter;


/**
    Creates a new ImageFont with no characters.
*/
public ImageFont() {
    this(null);
    firstChar = 0;
    characters = new Image[0];
}


/**
    Creates a new ImageFont and loads character images from
    the specified path.
*/
public ImageFont(String path) {
    if (path != null) {
        load(path);
    }

    // make the character used for invalid characters
    invalidCharacter =
        new BufferedImage(10, 10, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g = invalidCharacter.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(0,0,10,10);
    g.dispose();
}


/**
    Loads the image files for each character from the
    specified path. For example, if "../fonts/large"
    is the path, this method searches for all the images
    names "charXX.png" in that path, where "XX" is a
    decimal unicode value. Not every character image needs
    to exist; you can only do numbers or uppercase letters,
    for example.
*/
public void load(String path) throws NumberFormatException {
    // in this directory:
    // load every png file that starts with 'char'
    File dir = new File(path);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();

    // find min and max chars
    char minChar = Character.MAX_VALUE;
    char maxChar = Character.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
        int unicodeValue = getUnicodeValue(files[i]);
        if (unicodeValue != -1) {
            minChar = (char)Math.min(minChar, unicodeValue);
            maxChar = (char)Math.max(maxChar, unicodeValue);
        }
    }

    // load the images
    if (minChar < maxChar) {
        firstChar = minChar;
        characters = new Image[maxChar - minChar + 1];
        for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
            int unicodeValue = getUnicodeValue(files[i]);
            if (unicodeValue != -1) {
                int index = unicodeValue - firstChar;
                characters[index] = new ImageIcon(
                    files[i].getAbsolutePath()).getImage();
            }
        }

    }

}


private int getUnicodeValue(File file)
    throws NumberFormatException
{
    String name = file.getName().toLowerCase();
    if (name.startsWith("char") && name.endsWith(".png")) {
        String unicodeString =
            name.substring(4, name.length() - 4);
        return Integer.parseInt(unicodeString);
    }
    return -1;
}


/**
    Gets the image for a specific character. If no image for
    the character exists, a special "invalid" character image
    is returned.
*/
public Image getImage(char ch) {
    int index = ch - firstChar;
    if (index < 0 || index >= characters.length ||
        characters[index] == null)
    {
        return invalidCharacter;
    }
    else {
        return characters[index];
    }
}


/**
    Gets the string width, in pixels, for the specified string.
*/
public int stringWidth(String s) {
    int width = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
        width += charWidth(s.charAt(i));
    }
    return width;
}


/**
    Gets the char width, in pixels, for the specified char.
*/
public int charWidth(char ch) {
    return getImage(ch).getWidth(null);
}


/**
    Gets the char height, in pixels, for the specified char.
*/
public int charHeight(char ch) {
    return getImage(ch).getHeight(null);
}


/**
    Draws the specified string at the (x, y) location.
*/
public void drawString(Graphics g, String s, int x, int y) {
    drawString(g, s, x, y, LEFT | BOTTOM);
}


/**
    Draws the specified string at the (x, y) location.
*/
public void drawString(Graphics g, String s, int x, int y,
    int anchor)
{
    if ((anchor & HCENTER) != 0) {
        x-=stringWidth(s) / 2;
    }
    else if ((anchor & RIGHT) != 0) {
        x-=stringWidth(s);
    }
    // clear horizontal flags for char drawing
    anchor &= ~HCENTER;
    anchor &= ~RIGHT;

    // draw the characters
    for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
        drawChar(g, s.charAt(i), x, y, anchor);
        x+=charWidth(s.charAt(i));
    }
}


/**
    Draws the specified character at the (x, y) location.
*/
public void drawChar(Graphics g, char ch, int x, int y) {
    drawChar(g, ch, x, y, LEFT | BOTTOM);
}


/**
    Draws the specified character at the (x, y) location.
*/
public void drawChar(Graphics g, char ch, int x, int y,
    int anchor)
{
    if ((anchor & HCENTER) != 0) {
        x-=charWidth(ch) / 2;
    }
    else if ((anchor & RIGHT) != 0) {
        x-=charWidth(ch);
    }

    if ((anchor & VCENTER) != 0) {
        y-=charHeight(ch) / 2;
    }
    else if ((anchor & BOTTOM) != 0) {
        y-=charHeight(ch);
    }
    g.drawImage(getImage(ch), x, y, null);
}
}
```

I see it says the problem is at load in ImageFont but I dont know how to fix it.

Comment: What's on line 78 in `ImageFont` class?

Comment: What happens when the path you specify contains no files?

Comment: Surely the code sample could be made a little smaller. If the error occurs during loading, the code that draws the font isn't really relevant.

Comment: `fonts/big` and `fonts/medium` are you sure you have this folders?

Comment: i have the folders with the pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at image.ImageFont.load(ImageFont.java:78)
```

You have a NPE (Null Pointer Exception): this means that you have used a variable or an object which has not been initialized yet.

Example:

```
Button b;
b.setText("Text in my button"); // NULL POINTER EXCEPTION: b is a button but which button?!?
```

**Solution**

```
Button b = new Button();
b.setText("Text in my button"); // b now is a brand new button and it can be used.
```

You sir have this kind of problem :)

Comment: so should i replace that with the solution?

Comment: im sorry im not sure where to put it

Comment: @user2514575 of course not, I was only exaplaining what kind of problem your application has. Usually NPE are easily solvable by the developer just debugging a little his code. Go to line 78, check which object or variable could not be initialized and solve your NPE. It's not about solving one single but, it's about learning how to detect simple bugs and destroy them :) if you still have some problem you can ask us one more time of course.

Comment: im sorry i just cant figure it out can you please help?

Comment: Ok then, compile your  program once again and report bere the very line which there is notified NPE at. Id you have changed nothing, we expect to see a load(something)

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at image.ImageFont.load(ImageFont.java:78)
 at image.ImageFont.<init>(ImageFont.java:47)
 at image.ImageFontTest.init(ImageFontTest.java:26)
 at image.GameCore.run(GameCore.java:65)
 at image.ImageFontTest.main(ImageFontTest.java:11)
       Java Result: 1

Comment: And what is there at line 78? Plus user2514575 have you noticed that minChar is Character.MAX and viceversa?